# can you fly If you get in contact with lava

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Suppose I fall in lava lake, I have elytra equipped. I also have rockets for the boost if I can take off. 
But can elytra be activated in lava ?

Comment: As far as I know, Lava acts like Water for Elytra, so technically no? But the rockets should still work, at least if you have a Fire Resistance potion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes; tapping spacebar when floating in lava with an elytra equipped will allow you to start flying, and then rockets can be used to take off. Here's a gif of me doing so:

[image: Taking off with elytra in lava]

---

Additionally, here is the code that is run when a `START_FALL_FLYING` packet is sent:

[image: Code]

You can see that it makes sure the player isn't on ground, isn't in water, isn't already flying, and has a negative vertical velocity, but it does not check to make sure that the player isn't in lava.